# jQuery get attribute of every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

So at the beginning I want to point that I checked other threads and they didn't helped me.

So I got line like that:

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb');
```

And it gives me all those div elements, which is cool but I want only the hrefs values, so then I do

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').attr('href');
```

And it gives me only first element value which is how its supposed to be, according to jQuery documentation, which says that I should use .each() or .map() function, so I go with .each()

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').each(function(){$(this).find('a').attr('href')});
```

But instead of giving me the values, it gives me whole divs, like I would put code like this

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb');
```

I have checked one thread about this issue on this forum but the answer was to create an array inside the each function but I would prefer to get this array just as function return, not the global variable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to determine the set of elements that contains the property and iterate that:

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href');
});
```

EDIT2: want it in an array:

```
var myNewArray = [];
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').each(function(){
    myNewArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

**EDIT:** This is really just another example of the same idea:

```
var arrayofhref = $('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').map(function(){
     return $(this).attr('href');
 }).get();
```

and extend it to:

```
var commanlistofhref = $('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').map(function(){
     return $(this).attr('href');
 }).get().join();
```

**EDIT3:** creative use example: append to some element as text and put it in an object and show that;

```
var myobj = {
  hrefs: []
};
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb').find('a').each(function() {
  myobj.hrefs.push({
    href: $(this).attr('href')
  });
  $('#results').append($(this).attr('href') + '<br />');
});
$('#results').append(JSON.stringify(myobj));
```

Creative use to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/4mbh9ra4/

Comment: Note; what you DO with that inside the function is up to you; many options there

Comment: It seems nice but its returning whole <a> element, not only string with href.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href');` returns the string value, what you do with it is up to you; added some examples; you could do `somearray.push($(this).attr('href'));` also for example

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb a').each` returns the matching elements, not the return value inside the callback function, that's why you're getting all the divs:

```js
var hrefs = [];
var divs = $('div.fsl.fwb.fcb a').each(function(){
  hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
});

console.log(divs); //all divs
console.log(hrefs); //all hrefs
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
   <a href="http://foo.com">Foo</a>
</div>

<div class="fsl fwb fcb">
   <a href="http://bar.com">Bar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you mean that there is no other way than storing them in the array?

Comment: Yes there are, you can do many things,  but I don't know exactly what you were trying to achieve, so I made you a generic example, to illustrate what was happening.

Comment: I just want to get every href value from those <a> which are in div as returned values, not as the array, but I can go with array, it's not a problem, I just wanted less code. Thanks, Marcos!

Comment: There are many answers providing a way to do it, using `.map()` and `.get()`, but I wanted to explain you what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below using `map()` function.

```
var arr= $('div.fsl.fwb.fcb a').map(function(){
     return this.href;
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$('div.fsl.fwb.fcb > a').each(function(index, item){$(item).attr('href')});
```